# how to kill process in linux which was not killed

Tags: linux, ssh, ffmpeg

Hi I am developing a application  in linux for which I am writing a shell script to run ffmpeg and it was working fine but when  i want to kill the process of ffmpeg it was not working

```
kill 2628
```

where 2628 is my process id

Comment: I tried it but not working it just stop for 1 sec and again it starts

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/375984/how-can-i-stop-ffmpeg

Comment: killall will kill all running ffmpeg but i want to kill single ffmpeg process and remaining must run same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pkill` command to force kill the process it will definitely kill the process just try it